# Powershell code Telnet website or ping website If there is no connection Works restart iis

Tags: powershell

Please Help
I have a server win 2012

I have a There is website    www.forme.com.ph

I have a problem stopping iis sometimes

I want code Powershell

Do the following

Telnet website or ping website.

If there is a connection Nothing works .

If there is no connection Works restart  iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if you can "ping" a website:

```
#basic test to see if you can connect to the port
$tcp = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new()
try {
    $tcp.Connect('example.com', 443) 
    $tcp.Dispose()
} catch {
    #put code to restart IIS here
}
```

Or:

```
#more thorough test to see if you can get a response from the web server
try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://example.com' -UseBasicParsing -Method Head
} catch {
    #put code to restart IIS here
}
```

Restart IIS:

```
& {iisreset}
```